# Why can't I get this SLDS picklist to open?

Tags: html, css, salesforce

I want to use the SLDS picklist found **[here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/#flavor-picklist)**.

I'm using several other SLDS elements in my page and they work fine, I have included the necessary SLDS css.

The picklist doesn't actually work in the example they provide so I'm wondering if there is additional configuration required? The documentation does not mention any.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my understanding after reading the SLDS documentation the SLDS is just a CSS "framework". For the picklist to work (open) you need to include some Javascript and more specifically the picklist is "opened" by adding a class `slds-is-open` to the element (picklist). Apply the class to the div stated below.

```
<div class="slds-picklist slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click slds-is-open" aria-expanded="true">
```

I can't really make a demo out of this since the SLDS is so complicated to install but hopefully this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well those dropdowns require some kind of javascript or jquery so there should be a file you have to include. CSS just styles the content it doesen't make it work XD

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with desktop application only (no SalesForce1), a simple way to make it work without adding code is removing the `trigger--click`

Just let the div like this:

```
<div class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-is-open">  *//your list//*  </div>
```

And it will work when you put your mouse **over** the icon.

**It will have a weird behavior in SalesForce1** because you can't put your finger "over" without "clicking" the screen, **keep that in mind**.

PS: `slds-dropdown-trigger` is **deprecated** at the moment in SLDS documentation, keep that in mind too.

Answer (score 0):

if you not comfortable with JS you can use [this](http://aljs.appiphony.com/#!/picklists) JS library

or add  `slds-is-open` class on click event